# NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error while running java services

Tags: java, php, apache, ubuntu, localhost

when i am trying to run a java services through php file(xyz), it is throwing this error (Firebug) NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error http://127.0.0.1/dev/en/abc/xyz

/var/log/apache2/error.log is showing PHP Fatal error: Uncaught [[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: ReferenceClass failed: new com.intelligent.abc.main.RunABCHandler. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

While other java services are responding perfectly fine.

Can i get suggestion, so that i can get rid from this.

Comment: As the exception says "ClassNotFoundException"  , unit test your java service and make sure it compiles and works fine.

Comment: yes it is working on server, and i have checked out the code from the same place.

Comment: Then it should be something to do with the parameters you send, check those directly on web service using a tool such as SOAPUI.

Comment: parameters are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place, one more instance of services onto the given paths into the properties file:
like `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/ext`

Surprisingly it was throwing the error, because of due path.